# Pop Filter Repair

Tags: repair

My children have ripped my pop filter, and I was wondering if I could repair it myself on the cheap. It looks like I would just need to stretch a new piece of material over the plastic hoop and glue it on.

My questions are

1. Is the material used for a pop filter a special type, and if so, what is it called?
2. Would the material from a (new!) pair of ladies tights/stockings be as effective?
3. What would be an appropriate type of glue to use to attach it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. I have heard many people use old cloth hangers and stockings or hose to make pop filters.. It should work just fine IMO..

Comment: Yes, that's what I used to use - a pair of tights stretched over a wire coathanger. Was wondering though if the material on proper pop filters is somehow slightly better.

Comment: Is' the same type of material. It may be a bit thicker or thinner, but it will still stop the transients just fine.

Comment: any suggestions on the glue I should use? the frame is plastic